# Path is not available in Views filter criteria

Tags: views, path-aliases

I am creating a views with for node having fields **Title,Author,Created,Path(page url)**. Now how can I add exposed filter for path(page url) so that user can find the specific page content in list.

Once I try to add **Path** in filter criteria it not visible it only available in fields section.

Comment: `Once I try to add Path in filter criteria it not visible it only available in fields section.` Probably for a reason, who on earth uses paths as an exposed filter? You are probably the only person...

Answer (score 0):

You can add path in Filters section if you installed [views_url_alias](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_url_alias) module.

Please, take a look on screenshot.

[image: Views with Views URL alias in Filters]

I hope this helps.